# MapReduce result set skip and limit

Tags: java, mongodb, mapreduce

I am running this mongo MapReduce query in java

```
MapReduceCommand mrc = new MapReduceCommand(collection, map,reduce, null,MapReduceCommand.OutputType.INLINE,conditions);  
MapReduceOutput out = collection.mapReduce(mrc);
```

This work fine and return values , but how can i set 'skip' and 'limit' for these results ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to do this, but not exactly way which i want, first i have to save output to a new collection , like this

```
 MapReduceCommand mrc = new MapReduceCommand(collection, map,reduce,"result",MapReduceCommand.OutputType.REPLACE,conditions);  
 MapReduceOutput out = collection.mapReduce(mrc);
```

Then, we can set skip limit like this

```
    DBCursor rs = out.getOutputCollection().find() ;
    rs.skip(0).limit(10);
```

If any body knows to do this without saving map reduce results to temporary collection, please post it ,

thanks